# setActive propagating down the layout hierarchy

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view hierarchy like

```
LinealLayout (background holder, own onClickListener)
  ->LinealLayout (duplicateParentState=true)
    -->TextView (color changes with background, duplicateParentState=true)
    -->TextView (color changes with background, duplicateParentState=true)
  ->LinealLayout (image holder, own onClickListener, duplicateParentState=FALSE)
    -->ImageView (color INDEPENDENT, duplicateParentState=FALSE)
```

now, the root layout, each textview and the imageview have their own selector like

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <!-- activated -->
    <item android:color="@color/activated_clr" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:color="@color/deactivated_clr" android:state_activated="false"/>
</selector>
```

My problem is that programatically I want to, after clicking on the root layout, change its state to setActive to force the selected state. My problem is that this state is propagated down the hierarchy and not respecting the duplicateParentState flags. My image holder gets the state from the parent, activating the image when it shouldn't.

Other than changing the state holder to somewhere in the adapter/listener, is there any flag issues I may have causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're confusing `setActive()` and `setActivated()`. Their respective attributes are `android:state_active` and `android:state_activated`.